Confusion about the notation $k[t_1,\dots,t_n]$ in defining $(x−t_1)\cdots (x−t_n)\in k[t_1, \dots, t_n][x]$ as the general/universal polynomial
Aluffi defined in Algebra: Chapter 0, section 7.3

Let $t_1, \dots, t_n$ be indeterminates. The polynomial $P_n(x) := (x − t_1) \dots (x − t_n) \in \mathbb{Z}[t_1, \dots, t_n][x]$

as the general or universal polynomial of degree $n$. It is defined similarly on page 607 of D&F.
I am slightly confused by the notation $k[t_1, \dots, t_n]$ here. Is it literally a polynomial ring, or just a ring extension with field elements that change based on the polynomial we are working? Note that he claims later in a proof that $k(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ is the splitting field of a separable $P_n(x)$ over $k(s_1, \dots, s_n)$, where each $s_i$ is an elementary symmetric polynomial.

It is a polynomial ring. Or you can take them to be algebraically independent elements in $\mathbb{C}$ and then take a ring extension. Either way you get the same isomorphism class.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.
